# failed to get cookies in SFSafariviewcontroller

Tags: swift, xcode, webview, sfsafariviewcontroller, appauth

I am using `AppAuth` pods for authentication (https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS) and was wondering how Safari webkit is managing the application context for the cookies saved while authentication. 
 
I made sure I have a successful authentication then I tried few combinations to understand failed authentication behavior and tried to compare with my mac safari developer tools. What caught me off guard was that the safari webkit cookies were not visible to me programmatically. I am using below code to get the cookies.

```
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for: URL(string: "https://\(targetDomain)")!)
```

I also tried using developer console for mobile safari kit but as soon as the authentication flow gets completed the view is destroyed and information gets lost. So has anyone have come across this situation and figured how safari web kit isolates the cookies visibility.